# ClassCastException : Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object[]' to 'list.TestCastO<E>[]

Tags: java, generics

```
class TestCastO <E> {
        private E id;
        private String name;
        public TestCastO(E id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
public class TestCast<E> {
        private TestCastO<E> data[];
        public TestCast() {
            data = (TestCastO<E>[]) new Object[12];
        }
        public void getData() {
            for(int i=0; i< data.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(data[i]);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            TestCast<Integer> tc = new TestCast<>();
            tc.getData();`enter code here
        }
    }
```

Getting an exception on running the above snippet:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Llist.TestCastO; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [Llist.TestCastO; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: what is your question actually?

Comment: This fails for the same reason `String s = (String) new Object();` fails.  An Object cannot be treated like it’s a String.  An array of Object cannot be treated like it’s an array of String or an array of TestCastO.  Use `new TestCastO<?>[]` instead.

Comment: Used , data = (TestCastO<E>[]) new TestCastO<?>[10]; It works in runtime but still gives a warning at compile time that Unchecked cast: 'list.TestCastO<?>[]' to 'list.TestCastO<E>[]'. Although solved my problem. Thank you.